# Why are some commands like "apt" missing on Raspberry Pi 3 Model B with Ubuntu Core 20?

Tags: command-line, apt, dpkg, raspberrypi, ubuntu-core

I have Ubuntu Core 20 installed on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B, but the commands that I am trying keep failing. Commands that I have tried: `locate`, `apt`, `apt-get`, `dpkg`, `lsb_release`, and more, but they all tell me that the command was not found.

I looked them up using the `which` command, but it just outputs nothing and throws up no error. Other commands, like `date` and such do work and show up on `which`, but these ones do not and all of the guides and fixes I find just tell me to use `apt`, `apt-get`, `dpkg`, or `wget`, but none of these work at all.

How can I get these commands to work?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Ubuntu Core is a snap-only system.**

- Ubuntu Core does not use deb packages.
- Neither apt nor dpkg are available on Ubuntu Core.

If you want apt, then DON'T install Ubuntu Core.

- Ubuntu Core cannot be easily hacked to add deb packages -- it's MUCH easier to simply reinstall Ubuntu Server or Ubuntu Desktop, both include debs and apt.
- You can use apt inside LXD Containers and Virtual Machines hosted by Ubuntu Core, but not on the host itself.

Install additional software using the `snap` command.

- To see which Snaps include `wget`, try `snap search wget`.